# Calculated field from other fields in pivot table excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have this pivot table that is showing distinct count values. I cannot change the data base source so I need a calculated field to group the indicated headers below
[image]

For the purpose of my analysis ASW, BSW and SW mean the same thing.
So any time the calculated field sees that any of those headers has a 1, it should throw a 1.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way by adding a new conditional column to the query.

[image]